# Input array value in the same line using array size

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a array and user can fixed the array length.But i  want to input array value in the single line. when user add more cahrecter in the array length show out of boundary.
suppose

```
var len = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
char[] values = new char[len];
```

suppose len is 2, when user input in the same line abc and user press enter program show out of boundary.

but i do not this approach

- a
- b
- c

i want input same line using array size

Comment: I didn't downvote, but perhaps tell us the expected input and the expected output vs "your actual output"? Add in a [mcve] for good measure.

Comment: Store `abc` in a string and check the length of it. If it is more than `len` then you need to throw OutOfBound error. `var input = Console.ReadLine(); if(input.Length > len) throw new IndexOutOfBoundException();`

Answer (score 0):

Due to the nature of c# arrays, they are static and cannot be resized. that is why you are getting the error when trying to insert a value into a memory location not belonging to the `values` array you created

- it sounds like what you are looking for is something like this, per Caius Jard's comment

```cs
char[] array = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();
```

Comment: *c# cannot convert from string to char[]* - `char[] array = Console.ReadLine().ToCharArray();` ?

Comment: if that works then there is the solution! i wasn't aware that there was such a method for strings